# How do I remove the site name from the head title in drupal 8?

Tags: 8

The `<title>` element in the `<head>` of every page currently has the form
page_name | site_name. I would like to make this have the page name only site wide. I've found advice about how to do this in earlier drupal versions (eg [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35674/how-do-i-remove-the-site-name-from-the-page-title-on-a-particular-page)), but not for drupal 8. How is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Until metatag's module port has not finished you should code a bit for doing that.

If I were you I'll edit YOURTHEME.theme file and add this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for HTML document templates.
 *
 * Adds body classes if certain regions have content.
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    unset ($variables['head_title']['name']);
  }
```